# I'm working on a project but when i try to play it i have the error CS0031 Constant value true cannot be converted to a float

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioSource theMusic;

    public bool startPlaying;

    public BeatScroller theBS;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!startPlaying)
        {
            if (Input.anyKeyDown)
            {
                startPlaying = true;
                theBS.hasStarted = true;       <----------CS0031 error

                theMusic.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

THE ERROR IS AT THE LINE WHERE IT SAYS theBS.hasStarted = true;

Comment: This looks like Java? not C. Anyway I moved to `c#` as it seems to be `c#`. Please edit with the correct tag if it's not `c#`.

Comment: hasStarted is a float and you are trying to assign it a boolean.

Comment: What data type is the property hasStarted in the class BeatScroller?  Bets are...it's a float and not a bool.

Comment: First, print out what hasStarted is. The error, as stated by @Fredrik is that you're assigning a boolean to a float. So, once you confirm that hasStarted is float go into BeatController and fix your variable.

Answer (score 1):

`theBs.hasStarted` is a `float` and you are trying to assign it a boolean.